# Run all lines of a file at the same time

Tags: bash, while-loop

The while loop works fine.

But wondering if there is a way of running all lines from a file at the same time and then run the variables through the same set of commands instead of waiting each interface for 3 seconds ?

```
while read line; do
before=$(snmpwalk -v2c -c public 1.1.1.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16.$line | awk '{print $4}')
sleep 3
after=$(snmpwalk -v2c -c public 1.1.1.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16.$line | awk '{print $4}')
res=$(bc <<< "$after-$before")
zxc=$(echo "$res * 8 * 100 / (1000000000 * 3) "  | bc)
per=$(echo "scale=1; 100 * $zxc / (1000) "  | bc)
done < intfile.txt
```

Thnaks

Comment: Rebuild your processing code into 1 script.  Then call this 1 script in background, with each line as an argument.  Your while loop will therefore start as many instances of your processing script as you have lines in your intfile.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use [GNU's parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/sphinx.html)

Moving commands to a separate file **command.sh**:

```
before=$(snmpwalk -v2c -c public 1.1.1.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16.$1 | awk '{print $4}')
sleep 3
after=$(snmpwalk -v2c -c public 1.1.1.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16.$1 | awk '{print $4}')
res=$(bc <<< "$after-$before")
zxc=$(echo "$res * 8 * 100 / (1000000000 * 3) "  | bc)
per=$(echo "scale=1; 100 * $zxc / (1000) "  | bc)
```

Then execute **parallel** with intfile.txt as input:

```
 cat intfile.txt | parallel -j 5 'bash command.sh {}'
```

- : **j** flag sets how many jobs will run concurrently

Comment: it does work, however when left for some time it stops producing any results, its like if it is frozen, after some time I get...  parallel: SIGTERM received. No new jobs will be started. parallel: Waiting for these 1 jobs to finish. Send SIGTERM again to stop now.  Do you know by any chance what would be the solution ?

Comment: @Max Try `parallel -t -j1`. If it still fails, does it fail at the same line every time?

Comment: @Gonzalo Consider using s function instead. That way you do not need a separate file. https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example-calling-bash-functions

Comment: @Gonzalo Conside, its the same but in error log file I can see ./bash with every variable that the parallel ran and it is only getting bigger but the script still works for some time. In  a separate file I have "while true; cat intfile.txt | parallel -j 5 'bash command.sh {}'".

Comment: @Ole Tange, how would I do it with a single file ?using the -S function ? reading the examples cant make much out of it atm

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Gonzalo's answer you can move the `command.sh` into the same script using bash functions:

```
walk_one() {
    do_the_walk() {
      snmpwalk -v2c -c public 1.1.1.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16.$1 |
        awk '{print $4}'
    }
    before=$(do_the_walk $1)
    sleep 3
    after=$(do_the_walk $1)
    res=$(bc <<< "$after-$before")
    zxc=$(echo "$res * 8 * 100 / (1000000000 * 3) "  | bc)
    per=$(echo "scale=1; 100 * $zxc / (1000) "  | bc)
}
export -f walk_one

cat intfile.txt | parallel -j 5 walk_one {}
```